# Setting normals for ISSKeypoint3D in Point Cloud Library (PCL)

Tags: pointers, type-conversion, point-cloud-library, normals

I'm trying to compute ISS3D keypoints on a point cloud in PCL. I want to set
the normals because I'm not sure if the ISS keypoint estimation flips them
in the correct direction. However, when I try to set the normals like this

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > PointCloud;

PointCloud::Ptr detecISSKeypoints(PointCloud::Ptr cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr normals, float resolution) {
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr keypoints(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::ISSKeypoint3D<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB> detector;
  detector.setInputCloud(cloud);
  detector.setNormals(normals);
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr kdtree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  detector.setSearchMethod(kdtree);
  detector.setSalientRadius(6 * resolution);
  detector.setNonMaxRadius(6 * resolution);
  detector.setMinNeighbors(6);
  detector.setThreshold21(0.975);
  detector.setThreshold32(0.975);
  detector.setNumberOfThreads(4);
  detector.compute(*keypoints);
  return keypoints;
}
```

I get an error that `setNormals` is expecting a `const PointCloudNConstPtr&`. I tried to convert the pointer of the normals to `const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::ConstPtr`, however this didn't work.

How can I set the normals?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can set the normal for this detector. I used it but without put the normals and it worked well. I think they compute the normals inside the ISS code itself but I cannot say to you if the estimation flips are corrects...

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution for the conversion, I'll post it quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to set the normals like this:

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normalsCopy (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  copyPointCloud(*normals, *normalsCopy);
  boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal> > constNormals (normalsCopy);
  detector.setNormals(constNormals);
```

The problem is `ISSKeypoint3D` is only accepting `pcl::Normal`, not `pcl::PointNormal` and the pointer must be to a constant pointlcoud.